# reassigning values to a initialised two dimensional array in c++

Tags: c++

I have to assign value to the mat(two dimensional array within s) without using loop.

```
struct s{
 int mat[2][2];
};

int main()
{
 s *obj=new s[10];
 obj[0].mat[][]={{1,2},{5,6}};   /*error----how to assign value like this??*/
}
```

Comment: Arrays are not assignable in C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign the entire object:

```
int main()
{
    s obj { { {1,1}, {1,1} } };
    obj = s { { {2,2}, {2,2} } };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are not assignable in C+.

However `s` is an aggregate, so you can use directly a brace initializer :

```
struct s{
 int mat[2][2];
};

int main()
{
 s obj = { {1,2} , {5,6} }; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't : you'll have to use a loop.